# How do you make it that it doesn’t give an error if the role is wrong? Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am making an addrole command for my bot, but everytime someone gets a role wrong it give an error. I don’t know how to fix it so please help

Code:

```
if (!message.content.startswith(prefix) || message.author.client) return;
const arguments = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(‘‘);
const command = arguments.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === ‘addrole’) {
const suggestedRole = arguments[1] // role from the message 
    const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === suggestedRole) // trying to find the role 
    if(!role) message.channel.send(‘Role does not exist!’) // if the role doesn’t exist
    const target = message.mentions.members.first() // target 
    if(!target) message.channel.send(‘User not found!’) // if no target 
    target.roles.add(role) // adds the role to the target
}
```

Now you might be thinking ‘What if the role has two words’, I’m working on that, I just need help so that if the role doesn’t exist it doesn’t give an error, it just sends ‘Role not found’. Please help me, thanks. Sorry for lack of detail, don’t know what else to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could actually use try catch, which might seem a lot simpler to somebody who is not familiar with promises. that would look like

```
try{
    //will attempt to run the code in this try block
    const target = message.mentions.members.first() // target 
    if(!target) message.channel.send(‘User not found!’) // if no target 
    target.roles.add(role) // adds the role to the target
} catch {
    //will run if an error occurs in the try block
    message.channel.send(‘Role does not exist!’)
}
```

this works for pretty much the same reason my other solution does, but it is a bit different. i'm not going to explain it in depth like I did the last time, so instead, here's a simple explanation on try catch blocks and what they do: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp.

Answer (score 1):

`message.guild.roles.cache.find` will return a promise, so you need to deal with that promise before accessing the role. one way of doing this is with .then and .catch.

```
message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === suggestedRole)
.then((role)=>{
//what to do if the role does exist using the role parameter

}).catch(()=>{
//what to do if the role does not exist, in your case, 
message.channel.send(‘Role does not exist!’)
})
```

the reason why we need to do this is because as I said, cache.find() will return a promise. a promise can either return as fulfilled, or as rejected. if the role you are searching for does not exist, you will receive an unhandled promise rejection, which in some cases can crash your program. to stop this, we need to account for the different states that your promise can be in. we do this with .then and .catch. if your promise is fulfilled, the .then block is called. if it is rejected, the .catch block is called. with the .catch block, your code now knows what to do if it encounters an error, and in this case we are telling it to send a message saying "role not found.". I hope this code helps and that the explanation helped you understand some important concepts behind promises.

Answer (score 0):

This code will check if the role exists, if not sends an error message, and if exists it add the role to the member and will send "Can't add role" if an error occurs.

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'roleName');
if(!role) return message.channel.send('Role not found.')
const member = message.member;
member.roles.add(role).catch(() => { message.channel.send('Can\'t add role.') });
```